# active record update column id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to update active record id column its object. this looks simple but it's not working as I expected it to.

eg.

```
Lesson.first.update(:chapter_id => Chapter.find_by(:chapter_code => 'base'))
```

but this code is working

```
Lesson.first.update(:chapter_id => Chapter.find_by(:chapter_code => 'base').id)
```

I tried creating the association between the models but no luck. I just want to know why my code isn't working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first snippet, you are passing in an object (a `Chapter` instance) where an integer is expected, because you are attempting to assign `chapter_id`.  This is why the second snippet works, because you are also getting the integer id of the chapter.

You should also be able to assign the relation directly like so:

```
Lesson.first.update(:chapter => Chapter.find_by(:chapter_code => 'base'))
```

Comment: facepalm!
how could I miss that :(